# Retrieve all the major modes equipped with emacs

Tags: major-mode, help

I learned that [GNU Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Modes)

> Most major modes fall into three major groups. The first group
>   contains modes for normal text, either plain or with mark-up. It
>   includes Text mode, HTML mode, SGML mode, TeX mode and Outline mode.
>   The second group contains modes for specific programming languages.
>   These include Lisp mode (which has several variants), C mode, Fortran
>   mode, and others. The third group consists of major modes that are not
>   associated directly with files; they are used in buffers created for
>   specific purposes by Emacs. Examples include Dired mode for buffers
>   made by Dired (see Dired), Message mode for buffers made by C-x m (see
>   Sending Mail), and Shell mode for buffers used to communicate with an
>   inferior shell process (see Interactive Shell).

Most major modes fall into three major groups of Text, Programming and File.

How could I retrieve a list of all the major modes equipped with my emacs.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536304/emacs-stock-major-modes-list I think this question has no definite answer. Some major-modes are not in `auto-mode-alist` and some are not defined with `define-derived-mode`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To list major modes defined with `define-derived-mode` macro you can grep `el` files in `emacs-source/lisp` folder like `grep -A 1 '(define-derived-mode' **/*.el`

But maybe browsing built-in packages would be enough?

Those are with `built-in` status in the list provided by `M-x package-list-packages`.

Also `finder-by-keyword` which bound to `C-h p` will show packages grouped by keyword.

This one by @clemera: One can also check `auto-mode-alist`:

> Alist of filename patterns vs corresponding major mode functions

Comment: One can also check `auto-mode-alist`

Comment: @clemera Awesome!